# Why my choice batch command always selects first integer choice?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch

I created a simple menu of choices of numbers like the following:

```
@echo off
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 OR 3 to select your task, or 4 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Open MSOFFICE 2007
ECHO 2 - Open MSOFFICE 2010

CHOICE /N /T 10 /D 1 /C 12 /M "Press 1 for MSOFFICE 2007 or 2 for MSOFFICE2010 
Default is 1"
IF ERRORLEVEL==1 GOTO OFFICE2007
IF ERRORLEVEL==2 GOTO OFFICE2010

:OFFICE2010
C:\MSOFFICE2010.TXT

:OFFICE2007
C:\MSOFFICE2007.TXT
```

My problem is that when I press choice "2" it opens the file of choice "1"

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add "%" before and after ERRORLEVEL:

IF **%ERRORLEVEL%**==1 GOTO OFFICE2007 etc...

And you need to add `goto :EOF` in your OFFICE2010 section, otherwise you will execute both files.

```
:OFFICE2010
C:\MSOFFICE2010.TXT
goto :EOF

:OFFICE2007
C:\MSOFFICE2007.TXT
```

Comment: You are correct but now I notice that the cmd windows does not close even with EXIT command why?

Comment: because :EOF skips to the end of the file, you can add the exit command in your OFFICE2010 section for example.

Comment: I added Start c:\msoffice2010.txt and the cmd window now closes ok